# Django: row still displayed after being deleted - because of caching?

Tags: django, http, nginx, datatables, gunicorn

I've written a Django app that uses [DataTables](http://datatables.net/index). The problem is when I delete a row from the table it's still displayed in the table when running against nginx/gunicorn. However, it works correctly when I'm running against the Django test server. So if I start a server with this command line:

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.0.1:8000
```

everything works fine. That is, I delete the row, the table refreshes, and the deleted row is not displayed.

This is a summary of the HTTP calls:

```
// An initial GET command to populate the table
GET /myapp/get_list (returns a list to display)

// I now select a row and delete it which causes this POST to fire
POST /myapp/delete (deletes a row from the list)

// After the POST the code automatically follows up with a GET to refresh the table
GET /myapp/get_list (returns a list to display)
```

The problem is when I use nginx/gunicorn the second GET call returns the same list as the first GET including the row that I know has been deleted from the backend database.

I'm not sure it's a caching problem either because this is the response header I get from the first GET:

```
Date    Fri, 23 Dec 2011 15:04:16 GMT
Last-Modified   Fri, 23 Dec 2011 15:04:16 GMT
Server  nginx/0.7.65
Vary    Cookie
Content-Type    application/javascript
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Expires Fri, 23 Dec 2011 15:04:16 GMT
```

Comment: how do you delete the row? using what command?

Comment: I use oTable.fnDeleteRow( anSelected); at the client. I also send a POST request via ajax to the server (which works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved also by sending an added parameter to the server so that the browser doesn't cache the call. With jQuery you can simply use:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false});
```

Otherwise you must creat manually the parameter. Usually you create a timestamp

```
var nocache = new Date().getTime();
//send nocache as a parameter so that the browser thinks it's a new call
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django's add_never_cache_headers or never_cache decorator to tell the browser not to cache given request. Documentation is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers). I thinks it's cleaner solution than forcing the cache off in the javascript.

```
    from django.utils.cache import add_never_cache_headers

    def your_view(request):
        (...)
        add_never_cache_headers(response)
        return response

    from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

    @never_cache
    def your_other_view(request):
            (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
oTable.fnDeleteRow( anSelected, null, true );
```

and b.t.w what version of datatables do you use?

Comment: Unfortunately, That didn't help. I'm using version 1.8.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by changing

> GET /myapp/get_list

to

> POST /myapp/get_list

After doing this, I no longer get a cached response.